# Chrome incognito mode downloads a video rather than play it

Tags: google-chrome, video

I have a webpage which have a video tag.

When I set `src` attribute in javascript or html, it works well on chrome. But if I enter the incognito mode of Chrome, it downloads the video file rather than play it sometimes.

The file format is `.mp4`, the size of it is 112MB. I think it happens when it was large. However I want to play it on the webpage. not download it.

What's wrong with it and how can I fix this problem?

--------------**UPDATE**--------------

```
<video preload="auto" class="video" width="413px" height="330px" />
<input name="path" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $path; ?>" />
<script>
    var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
    video.src = $("input[name=path]").val();
</script>
```

Comment: <video preload="auto" class="video" width="413px" height="330px" src="http://localhost.com/videos/20160223_152925_admin.mp4"></video>

But it generated dynamically in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [`<video>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) tag is malformed.

The correct format should be:

```
<video width="413" height="330" controls>
    <source src="yourvideofile.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```